# running a stored proc from a different db

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

so I have a sproc in a db.. lets call this db `A`. This db makes use of tables (`t1, t2`) in another db. Lets call this db `B`.

okay, so the way i call it right now is: `A.dbo.My_Proc` but i get another error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.t1'.

so how i tried supplying a parameter. In my Sproc i do, `select * from @dbname.dbo.t1` 
however that results in an error. I can't put the sproc in db `B`.

While it is sufficient to hardcode it (if there is a way), db `B` changes every year, so it would be nice to "supply" a database.

I tried using `use B; go` but it gives me error saying can't have that in a sproc.

Comment: Does the account you ran the `A.dbo.My_Proc` have permissions to the A database?

Comment: yes. i mean currently it all works if i type it in manually. like `B.dbo.table1`  from the sproc.. but i'd like `B` to be supplied in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a synonym:

**EDIT**: I see now that the synonym is needed for the table, not the proc. Got them switched. So you could create a synonym in database A for the table in database B:

```
USE A;
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.t1 FOR B.dbo.t1;
```

Then your procedure in A could simply say:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.t1;
```

Without having to manually supply the database name at all, the query knows (based on the synonym) to get the data from the table in database B. When the database B changes to C, you can simply:

```
DROP SYNONYM dbo.t1;
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.t1 FOR C.dbo.t1;
```

If you used "real" database names in your narrative as opposed to arbitrary A/B names, it might lead to easier comprehension. Just a suggestion. :-)

**/EDIT**

The other option is to pass in the database name and construct via dynamic SQL. E.g. instead of select * from @dbname.dbo.t1 (which will never work), you could do:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbname) + '.dbo.t1;';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

But if this other database name really only changes once a year, I suggest that the synonym route is better overall.

Comment: +1 for the synonym - I was going to bring up Dynamic SQL but I think the synonym is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: I dont understand how to use the synonym route? can you give  a more concrete example please? THANK YOU!

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection vulnerabilities resulting from straightforward `@dbname` concatenation into the executed SQL.

Comment: @Remus, I assumed this @dbname parameter doesn't come from the client-facing app, since it sounds like this is an architectural choice implemented by the programmers, not a user choice passed in through all tiers. Also this is why I suggested that dynamic SQL is not the optimal solution.

Comment: There is an access db that calls the sproc and creates a report out of it. While its a "client" application, it will only be used internally within the department. What route should I go with? I am not worried about SQL injection since they will not be typing in a name for the db everytime it changes.

Comment: I still think the synonym is the better route. It's easier for you to control especially if you are referencing this table from more than one procedure.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `exec someDB.dbo.SomeProc` the execution context switches to `someDB`. So if the procedure issues a `SELECT FROM dbo.t1` then `dbo.t1` must be in `someDB`. IF you want the procedure to select from a 'supplied' database then the procedure must use [dynamic-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html):

```
create procedure someProc
   @dbname sysname
as
begin
...
set @sql = N'SELECT ... FROM ' + quotename(@dbname) +N'.dbo.t1';
exec sp_executesql @sql;
...
end
```